# Why is my SQL Server consuming so much memory?

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql-server-2019

I have a 64GB Windows Server 2019 Standard server in my TEST Server.

I have SQL Server 2019 CU9 Developer Edition and my the instance is consuming 21,199 MB as shown in `sql_physical_memory_in_use_MB`.

I have 4 user databases.  Their sizes are approximately 5GB, 2GB, 400MB, and 200MB.

My `tempdb` is configured to be 8GB at instance start-up.

I'm trying to understand why my instance is using 21GB of memory.  Just worried about a possible memory leak.

Can anyone calm my nerves?

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN ([database_id] = 32767) THEN 'Resource Database' ELSE DB_NAME (database_id) END) AS 'Database Name',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ([is_modified] = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DirtyPageCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ([is_modified] = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS CleanPageCount,
    count(*)AS TotalPageCount,
    cast(count(*) * 8192.0 / (1024.0 * 1024.0) as decimal(8,2)) as BufferPoolMB
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY database_id
ORDER BY TotalPageCount desc
GO
```

OUTPUT

| Database Name | DirtyPageCount | CleanPageCount | TotalPageCount | BufferPoolMB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SFI_WMS | 55 | 805665 | 805720 | 6294.69 |
| tempdb | 18648 | 210842 | 229490 | 1792.89 |
| DBAtools | 483 | 82035 | 82518 | 644.67 |
| Resource Database | 0 | 3896 | 3896 | 30.44 |
| msdb | 42 | 1898 | 1940 | 15.16 |
| master | 24 | 766 | 790 | 6.17 |
| ReportServer | 4 | 476 | 480 | 3.75 |
| ReportServerTempDB | 0 | 308 | 308 | 2.41 |
| model | 0 | 245 | 245 | 1.91 |

```
SELECT 
    physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024 AS sql_physical_memory_in_use_MB, 
    large_page_allocations_kb/1024 AS sql_large_page_allocations_MB, 
    locked_page_allocations_kb/1024 AS sql_locked_page_allocations_MB,
    virtual_address_space_reserved_kb/1024 AS sql_VAS_reserved_MB, 
    virtual_address_space_committed_kb/1024 AS sql_VAS_committed_MB, 
    virtual_address_space_available_kb/1024 AS sql_VAS_available_MB,
    page_fault_count AS sql_page_fault_count,
    memory_utilization_percentage AS sql_memory_utilization_percentage, 
    process_physical_memory_low AS sql_process_physical_memory_low, 
    process_virtual_memory_low AS sql_process_virtual_memory_low
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

OUTPUT

| sql_physical_memory_in_use_MB | sql_large_page_allocations_MB | sql_locked_page_allocations_MB | sql_VAS_reserved_MB | sql_VAS_committed_MB | sql_VAS_available_MB | sql_page_fault_count | sql_memory_utilization_percentage | sql_process_physical_memory_low | sql_process_virtual_memory_low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21199 | 0 | 0 | 124464 | 21461 | 134093263 | 9673913 | 100 | 0 | 0 |

```
SELECT c.value, c.value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations c WHERE c.[name] = 'max server memory (MB)';
```

| value | value_in_use |
| --- | --- |
| 60288 | 60288 |

Comment: I disagree with the dupe closure and answer here.  It seems unusual that SQL Server is using 21 GB of memory when there are only ~8 GB of user databases on the whole instance.  I've voted to reopen the question.  In the meantime, you could inspect what components are using all that RAM by querying `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks` (see [this post](https://www.sqlshack.com/monitoring-memory-clerk-and-buffer-pool-allocations-in-sql-server/) for an example query).

Comment: OP has max memory set way above 21GB, I don't think this is unusual behavior at all (I originally VtC)

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnM Sure, but SQL Server doesn't just acquire memory for no reason.  If OP loaded all of those tables into memory, there would be 8.5 GB.  I think it's worth looking into why an additional 12.5 GB have been allocated. It's not like there has [never been a leak patched before](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222734/tokenandpermuserstore-clear-decreases-cpu-usage-for-a-short-period-of-time) 

Comment: @sherveyj - please take a quick look at how I formatted the output in my edit to your question, then add the output of `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS;` from your SQL Server using that style of formatting.  It's interesting that your instance is consuming 4x the amount of memory required by just the buffer pool.  Not unheard of, just interesting.  The output from the DBCC command will show us exactly what is using memory.

Comment: How does one cut/paste output in here that is large... it always exceeds the max size of the comment window?

Comment: I do have a linked server that is connected from this SQL Server to Oracle on SUSE.   But the link hasn't really been tested yet by the App.   So maybe I ran 3 or 4 selects to prove that the link worked.

Comment: @shervetj - add really long stuff to https://gist.github.com and provide the link in your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my SQL Server consuming so much memory?

You're looking at total process memory, and one particular consumer of memory.  To drill down from total process memory and get a high-level allocation of SQL Server's memory use use `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks`, eg:

```
select type,name, (pages_kb + virtual_memory_committed_kb + awe_allocated_kb) / 1024. committed_mb
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks 
order by committed_mb desc
```

or the old-school

`dbcc memorystatus`

If you see large amounts of process memory (large_page_allocations_kb + locked_page_allocations_kb + virtual_address_space_committed_kb) that can't be accounted for by the memory clerks, see if you have any OleDb drivers for linked server loaded in-process.  They allocate memory outside of the SQL Server memory managers.

The two biggest consumers of memory are the the buffer pool and the lock manager.  Both of these will allocate memory and not release it unless the system is under memory pressure.

```
MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL Client-Default        9801MB
OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER  Lock Manager : Node 0 6929MB
```

So there's your answer.  Since it's started SQL Server has at some point grown the buffer pool to 9GB and the lock manager memory to 7GB, which accounts for enough of your 21GB to indicate that you don't really have a problem.

See related: [memory used by Locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43452/memory-used-by-locks)

Comment: `You're looking at total process memory, and one particular consumer of memory`. He is actually not looking at one particular consumer but *total physical memory* which includes almost all consumptions. 2nd thing total server memory is not always equal to physical memory value returned by sys.dm_os_process_memory.

Comment: type     name   committed_mb
MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL  Client-Default  9801.425781
OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER  Lock Manager : Node 0 6929.070312
CACHESTORE_SQLCP   SQL Plans  186.539062
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG   Client-Default  76.687500
MEMORYCLERK_QUERYDISKSTORE_HASHMAP Client-Default  76.078125
MEMORYCLERK_SOSMEMMANAGER  SOSMemoryManager 72.765625
MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE   SOS_Node  66.367187
CACHESTORE_PHDR    Bound Trees  42.132812
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR   Client-Default  28.500000
USERSTORE_SCHEMAMGR   SchemaMgr Store  19.195312

Comment: dbcc memorystatus; 
Process/System Counts Value
Available Physical Memory 39426875392
Available Virtual Memory 140606952742912
Available Paging File 107816660992
Working Set 22408749056
Percent of Committed Memory in WS 100
Page Faults 10797460
System physical memory high 1
System physical memory low 0
Process physical memory low 0
Process virtual memory low 0

Comment: @sherveyj I told you that you do not have problem but few peoples had other wrong thought. IF possible restart SQL Server, since this is DEV. and you would start seeing things normal again.

Comment: Yup I can restart.  Left it untouched in case other queries needed to be run and curious if it will grow any larger - it kind of seems to have leveled off.  After the particular DB is initially loaded from data formally from Oracle.  I will add this DB to an AG and it will be part of a 2 node WFC.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just worried why my instance size is 21GB. Just worried about a memory leak. Can anyone calm my nerves?

Calm down, this is NOT a memory leak. You might have either set `max server memory` somewhere around 21 GB or might have not set it all and SQL Server would have used 21 GB (which is lot less likely). Please also note once SQL Serve uses a memory portion it will not release unless it sees need of that memory by some other process or low memory notification is flagged by SQL resource monitor. This is how SQL Server memory code is written. You have 5.5 GB of total data and almost 4 times the memory at some point of time your all data will be in memory and SQL Server will not release memory as reading from memory is much much faster than that from disk.

Read [Memory Management Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yeah - This is a 64GB memory server in TEST.   I have max mem for SQL Server set at 58GB.  Just was wondering why its so bloaty in size and my data was much smaller.  I also dont have memory optimized TEMPDB enabled.   Were going to be live with 2019 CU9 in production in maybe a month or so using AG's.

Comment: If you have set max server memory to 58GB and as per `sys.dm_os_process_memory` output it is using 21GB, this is totally normal so relax. If you go on production my advice would be to lower max server memory a bit to 57 GB and give OS and other components a total of 7 GB. Please keep monitoring the memory via counters.